# How to pass id in url in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in ruby on rails and i am trying to pass id in url from one controller to another controller. And i am getting this error.

Couldn't find Tournament without an ID

And here is my code:
matches View

```
<h2 class="text-center mt-4"><%= @tournaments.id %></h2>
<h2 class="text-center mt-4"><%= @tournaments.title %></h2>
<p>
    <% @players = @tournaments.player_ids %>
    Players = <%= @players.uniq %>
</p>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-8 mt-4">
            <div class="card text-center shadow mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <div class="card-header font-italic">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <%= link_to "Edit", edit_tournament_path(@tournaments), class: "btn btn-outline-info" %>
                <%= link_to "Delete", tournament_path(@tournaments), method: "delete", class: "btn btn-outline-danger", data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete?"} %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><%= link_to "All Tournaments", root_path, class: "btn btn-outline-primary float-right" %></p>
    <p><%= link_to "Schedules", matches_path(@touraments), class: "btn btn-outline-primary float-right" %></p>
</div>
```

This is my another controller where i want this data:

```
class MatchesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @match = Tournament.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Comment: Typo: change `@touraments` to `@tournaments` in `matches_path(@touraments)`, also the name of the variable should be `@tournament` instead of `@tournaments`

Comment: looks like you have a typo, second-from-last line of the view should be `@tournaments` not `@touraments`.  As a style comment, the `@tournaments` variable should be singular not plural. It helps you and others to understand your code better.

Comment: @Deepesh thanks but still getting same error

Comment: Can you share the routes? I think it should be `params[:tournament_id]` instead of `params[:id]` on `MatchesController`

Answer (score 0):

I'll advise you to check your `params` before assignation. I'm almost sure that you'll find something like

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"matches", "action"=>"index", "tournament_id"=>"666"} permitted: false>
```

Which means you simple need to adjust your controller with:

```rb
class MatchesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @match = Tournament.find(params[:tournament_id])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

An index route does not accept an `id` by default, so actually Rails will be interpreting the tournament id as a format and creating a URI like `/matches.13` based on your code.

Instead you need to actually pass it as a parameter like this: `matches_path(tournament_id: @tournaments)` and then in your controller it will be available as `params[:tournament_id]`